# Snap.load() external SVG fails to Load

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

**PROBLEM**:
I'm using Snap.svg to create some basic interactive graphics, but for some reason I can't get my external SVG file to load using `Snap.load()`. I've pulled code straight from the [tutorial](http://snapsvg.io/start/) at snap.io and checked and double-checked the docs. My SVG file renders in the browser fine, it just doesn't display inside the Snap SVG. Other shapes (i.e. not pulled in using `Snap.load()` ) do display.

**CODE**:
I've boiled my example down to the most simple HTML and SVG files imaginable, and the Snap.load() method still isn't working for me. Does anyone see what I'm missing?

*HTML*:

```
<head>
  <style media="screen">
            #svg {
                width: 300px;
                height: 300px;
            }
  </style>
  <script src="snap.svg-min.js"></script>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
</head>
<body>
  <svg id="svg"></svg>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var s = Snap("#svg");
    Snap.load("svgtest.svg");
  </script>
</body>
```

*SVG (originally exported from Illustrator)*:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="100px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" enable-background="new 0 0 100 100" xml:space="preserve">
<rect x="14" y="33" fill="#2BB673" width="70" height="30"/>
</svg>
```

**UPDATE**:
Updated the code as per @Ian's suggestion -

```
var s = Snap("#svg");
Snap.load("http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/images/struct/Use01.svg", onSVGLoaded ) ;

function onSVGLoaded( data ){ 
    s.append( data );
}
```

- but still no display of external SVG. I tried using an [SVG from w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/images/struct/Use01.svg) just to be sure it wan't a problem with the file itself or my domain.

Comment: I think the problem you are now having is that you aren't able to load in remote external files. Typically the file would be on the same server. (You may be able to load some files depending upon access control settings on the server I would guess). So it depends a lot if the original question is for a local file as described.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The load function takes a callback, as loading can take some time. So I think you would do something like the following...

```
var s = Snap("#svg");
Snap.load("svgtest.svg", onSVGLoaded ) ;

function onSVGLoaded( data ){ 
    s.append( data );
}
```

Edit: There may be some access control issues if not accessing from the same server as the script, check the console log for any errors.

Comment: Sure enough - access control errors showed up in the console. When I changed to an svg on the same server, it loaded. Thanks @Ian!

Answer (score 5):

I was having exactly this problem in Internet Explorer only, and it turned out to be because the SVG file I was loading in was a minified one from which the doctype had been removed. Other browsers were ok without the doctype, but leaving the doctype in fixed the problem in IE as well:

```
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
```

In case, like me, you're using Grunt to minify SVGs, you can leave the doctype in by adding the following option to your Gruntfile:

```
svgmin: {
    options: {
        plugins: [
            { removeDoctype: false }
        ]
    }
    // etc...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a small bug in the distribution - see https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/Snap.svg/issues/196.  The suggested fix works correctly.  The online demo works because it is referencing a much older build of the library.

Answer (score 0):

With version 0.5.1 installed. The code in the correct answer above needs to be re-written as follows to work:

```
var s = Snap();
Snap.load("svgtest.svg", onSVGLoaded ) ;

function onSVGLoaded( data ){ 
    s.append( data );
}
```